# question on probability of percentage of accuracy

Tags: probability

in a concealed box, if we have R number of red balls and W number of white balls, we only know total number of balls, T=R+W, and we don't know exactly R or W.

if we take out x balls, where x < T, we see n white ones and m red ones.

is there a function f(n, m, T) that we can use to express R/T or W/T with certain accuracy in term of +/-p%?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Consider the *relative probability* of $$p(R) = \binom{R}{m} \times \binom{T-R}{n}.$$  This is a job for [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: Do you take out the $x$ balls with or without replacement?

Comment: The comment of @Arthur raises an interesting question that I overlooked.  My previous comment assumed that the selection was without replacement.

Comment: take x balls out of T balls, without putting them back.

Comment: You may also want a prior distribution for $R$